# Weird output using ROI (opencv C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having difficulties using ROI using opencv c++.

I have a sequence of images which are stored in a vector. The vector image contained big blob and small blob. I want to remove the small blobs for every vector image. However, there is something wrong with the output result where if the small blobs in current vector image was removed, it will affect the blobs region for the next vector image (and previous vector image). Is there something wrong with ROI opencv c++? Below is sample code:

```
vector<Mat> finalImg;
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < srcImg.size(); i++) {
    vector<vector<Point> > contoursFinal;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchyFinal;

    Mat tempV_img;
    srcImg[i].copyTo(tempV_img);

    cv::findContours( tempV_img, contoursFinal, hierarchyFinal, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0,0) );

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < contoursFinal.size(); j++) {

        Rect r = cv::boundingRect( contoursFinal[j] );
        int heightChar = r.height;

        /// Set image region of interest
        cv::Rect ROI(r.x-1, r.y-1, r.width+2, r.height+2);
        Mat srcImg_crop = srcImg[i](ROI);

        cv::namedWindow("cropImg (bf)", 0);
        cv::imshow("cropImg (bf)", srcImg_crop);

        if(heightChar < srcImg[i].rows*0.90){
            srcImg_crop.setTo(0);
        }

        cv::namedWindow("cropImg (af)", 0);
        cv::imshow("cropImg (af)", srcImg_crop);
        cv::waitKey(0);

        if(cv::countNonZero(srcImg_crop) != 0) {
            finalImg.push_back(srcImg_crop);
        }
        srcImg_crop.release();
    }
    cv::namedWindow("Sorted Final", 0);
    cv::imshow("Sorted Final", finalImg[i]);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    contoursFinal.clear();
    hierarchyFinal.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all,

I just figured it out. Below shows the trick.

```
vector<Mat> tempV;
tempV.clear();
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < srcImg.size(); i++) {

    Mat temp;
    srcImg[i].copyTo(temp);

    tempV.push_back(temp);

    temp.release();
}
```

Instead of using srcImg[i]. I replace it with a new vector tempV[i]. Then it will not affect the previous as well as next vector image.